# Как переиспользовать запрос к api в разных файлах js?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Контекст: создал метод на php, который проверяет валидность токена в куках браузера для автоматической авторизации, и сделал запрос к файлу через классовый метод на js. (этот самый классовый метод находится в отдельном файле, где прописаны остальные запросы)
Проблема такая: классовый метод нужно переиспользовать импортами в разных файлах js, но в каждом из них пути к методу на php отличаются, что делает невозможным переиспользование.
Почему так происходит, если запрос находится в одном файле? Как решить данную проблему?

Вот сам классовый метод:

```
checkSignIn() {
    return fetch('components/api/checksignin', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: this._headers
    })
    .then(res => this._getResult(res))
  }
```

Comment: используйте не относительный путь а `HTTPS-протокол` т.е. полный путь `https://www.site/api/checksignin/` и т.п.

Comment: немножко подушню, причём тут https-протокол? Возможно лучше будет использовать корневой относительный путь вида ./components/api/checksignin

Comment: в этом и проблема, относительные пути работают криво в данном случае, мужик сверху правильно сказал, ну, по крайней мере, у меня все заработало. спасибо ему, кстати.

Comment: относительные пути работают криво, а корневые относительные пути не будут работать криво. Они начинаются с ```./``` Это гарантирует что путь будет начинаться от корневого каталога. Мужик сверху сказал правильно, но например если вам надо будет перенести скрипт на другой сайт то каждый раз придется переписывать код. В случае корневого пути такой проблемы не будет. И да ```HTTPS-протокол``` тут совершенно не причем